# Import, Export TSV Laravel

Tags: csv, laravel-5

I am working to import, export TSV in Laravel but no solution. Please help me, thanks.
I trying

```
$headers = [
            'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
            ,   'Content-type'        => 'text/tab-separated-values'
            ,   'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=category.tsv'
            ,   'Expires'             => '0'
            ,   'Pragma'              => 'public'
        ]; 
array_unshift($result, array_keys($result[0]));
```

```
    $callback = function() use ($result)
    {
        $FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            fputcsv($FH, $row);
        }
        fclose($FH);
    };

    return \Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $headers = [
                'Content-type' => 'text/tsv',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=file' . date('Y-m-d:H-i-s') . '.tsv',
                'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
                'Expires' => '0'
            ];
            $callback = function () use ($report) {
                $fileHandle = fopen('php://output', 'w');
                foreach ($report as $row) {
                    fputcsv($fileHandle, $row, "\t");
                }
                fclose($fileHandle);
            };
            return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)